# How to count the number of elements in one input

Tags: java, arrays

I hope you can help me with my task. I have tried to research different sites for this, but can't find the specific one.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{

    public static void main(String []args){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Input: ");
        String arr = input.nextLine();
        //System.out.println(arr.length);
    }
}
```

Let us say that I've input 3, 2, 1, 5, 6 then the output should be 5. Another example is I have inputted 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 then the output should be 6. It should count how many integers in the text are there in just one input.

Comment: ok, so what is stopping you? Just use the split method on the inputted String, and check the length of the returning array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you getting the input line you can split it by `,` so you will get an array of elements and the length of it is the number of elements you want

```java
public static void main(String []args){
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.print("Input: ");
    String arr = input.nextLine();
    int numberOfElement = arr.split(",").length;
}
```

The problem with your code is that you used `arr.length()` and this is the number of char in the input string not the number of elements for examples

```
"1, 2, 3, 4, 5".length() -> 13 char
"1, 2, 3, 4, 5".split(",").length -> 5 element
```